# Higgs Lagrangian and massive/massless fields

Tags: field-theory, higgs, symmetry-breaking

In QFT yesterday we were talking about Higgs/SSB and mass terms in Lagrangian. Our professor wrote down some lagrangians
and asked us to explain certain things and also if it is for massive or massless field. One of them was this
Lagrangian (not a realistic one I think)

$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu \phi )^2 - e^{m \phi} + \lambda \phi^4 $

and we said this cannot represent massive field since there is no $\phi^2$ term therefore $m = 0$. He said we are wrong and the point is
that mass terms are not always available by inspection of $\phi^2$ term in some complex Lagrangians. The mass term could be hidden.
This confused us. Can anyone explain
why this is Lagrangian describing massive field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can
demonstrate that this Lagrangian represents a massive field. You do this by looking at the exponential term $e^{m\phi}$ in

$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu \phi )^2 - e^{m \phi} + \lambda \phi^4$

and performing a Taylor expansion. That is

$e^{m\phi} = 1 + m \phi + m^2 \large \frac{\phi^2}{2} + ....$

This means the Lagrangian can now be written

$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu \phi )^2 + ... - m^2 \large \frac{\phi^2}{2} + $ $....+ \lambda \phi^4$

where the only term in the expansion involving $m^2$ is explicit. So this Lagrangian does indeed represent a massive field.

Comment: Shouldn't we define $\chi=\phi+c$ with $c$ chosen so the potential $V$ satisfies $\left.\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial\chi}\right|_{\chi=0}=0$, then compute the squared mass as $\left.\tfrac{\partial^2V}{\partial\chi^2}\right|_{\chi=0}$?

Comment: The Lagrangian is defined as T - V not T - (derivatives of V).

Comment: What's your point?

Comment: What, $V=e^{m(\chi-c)}-\lambda (\chi-c)^4$?

Comment: And what exactly can you do with this? There still is no $\phi^2$ term.

Comment: We're agreed you have to take the second derivative due to no quadratic term being explicit. My point is you have to shift the field first to delete the linear term implicit in the first derivative.